# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ is returning only 100 records, I want to fetch all the record present in Azure AD

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ is returning only 100 records, I want to fetch all the record present in Azure AD.

I have tried with above API to but it always gives me 100 records and with top, I am able to fetch only 999 records. But I have more than 100k records and want to fetch at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ returns a property called @odata.nextlink. Use [@odata.nextlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) to request more pages of user data.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch all user at a time? I want to fetch all record at one shot in data factory pipeline?

Comment: The only scenario where all users may be fetched from a single request is if the organization had fewer than 100 users. You will need page through the result set. What platform are you using? We have may have a PageIterator to simplify this for you

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to fetch all users with one request but you could wirte a method getting all users for you. The following code is requesting the first 100 users. Afterwards it is calling the next 100 users until there is no more users.

It is only a work around. **You should keep in mind that this function needs a long time to run**

```
    public async Task<List<GraphApiUser>> GetAllCloudUserAsync()
    {
        var query = "/users";
        var response = await SendGraphApiRequest(HttpMethod.Get, query);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetMultipleUserResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        var result = new List<GraphApiUser>();
        result.AddRange(data.value);
        var debugCounter = 1;

        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.NextLink))
        {
            response = await SendGraphApiRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/"+data.NextLink);
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetMultipleUserResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            result.AddRange(data.value);
            debugCounter++;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

`GetMultipleUserResponse`-Class looks like that:

```
public class GetMultipleUserResponse
{
    public List<GraphApiUser> value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("odata.nextLink")]
    public string NextLink { get; set; }
}
```

The `GraphApiUser`-Class looks diffrent from AD to AD because everyone is able to define own claims. Setting up this class belongs to you!

Sending a request can be done like this:

```
    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendGraphApiRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, string query,
        string json = "")
    {
        HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
        var requestUri = "Your Ressource Id" + "Your Tenant" + "your query"+ "your api version";

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, requestUri);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GetYourTokenHere());
        request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.SendAsync(request);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(error);
            Debug.WriteLine("Error Calling the Graph API: \n" +
                            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
            return null;
        }

        return response;
    }
```